# C++ a NULL pointer in the STL container

Tags: c++, access-violation, tr1, fatal-error, unordered-set

I am, unfortunately, not working on a program developed by myself fully. 
 I recently I noticed a Visual Studio Fatal Error on operator-- of unordered_set, which was called from simple insertion of a pointer to unordered_set. After reviewing the locals, I've noticed that set only has 2 elements last of which is NULL (so I suppose that's what it crashed on). Now to the question: How (theoretically) can an unordered_set (or any other STL container) get a NULL pointer as one of its elements. Program is multi-threaded, but according to my reviews, that part of code should only be accessed from one thread. Thanks.

Call stack and parts of source code for those who are interested:
 http://privatepaste.com/c8e7f35a4e (PushToProcessed is called from Object itself, it passes reference to itself, so cannot be NULL)

Comment: Some code would be great

Comment: You'll probably need to post the code

Comment: unordered_set<Object*>

 Code it errors on is simple _processQueue.insert(obj);

Comment: `unordered_set` is not part of the standard template library, per se. It's an extension in tr1. (And also implemented well in boost.)

Comment: oh well, still actual for other containers (of stl)

Comment: The privatepaste.com link doesn't include the source code necessary to reproduce or study the situation you mention.

Comment: @Stranger:  `Object *`?  Ewww.  That's not a good way to do things in C++, although it's quite common in some other languages.

Answer (score 6):

Sets can contain pointers which can be NULL.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::vector<int *> foo;
    foo.push_back (NULL);
    std::cout << foo.size () << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

A container can easily contain a NULL value. Are you talking about the internals of a container getting messed up?

Answer (score 4):

a NULL is a perfectly valid pointer value.  If a NULL is passed in, it will be treated just like any memory address.  Since you're seeing only 2 entries I would wager a guess that what you really are seeing is many NULL pointers being "added" to your set but since it is a set only one copy retained.

Edit:

To test my hypothesis of many items being added all of NULL value why not put in a simple call to cout stating "New item added with address = " the value of the pointer.  Bet you'll be surprised.

Comment: a NULL pointer cannot be added to there, theres just no way to :o

Comment: Without your code I can only make the assumption you've got a container of raw pointers which do allow NULL.

Comment: Cannot be added? You mean I can't go `container.insert(0)`?

Comment: It can be added theoretically, but my pointer can never be NULL (the only one place in program I insert to that set)

Comment: Stranger, are your surprised that there's a `NULL` in your container, which you didn't put there?

Comment: yes, object puts itself into that set (by calling a function), null checks are also persistent.

Comment: Are you using the pointers "raw" or using some kind of smart pointer wrapper?

Comment: Can you please post a minimal test case that reproduces it? Or at least snippets of the code that inserts and removes and checks the container?

Comment: I would add an assert() before the insert() to check the pointer definitely isn't NULL.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a container pointer value can be set via a dereferenced non-const iterator as in (*iter) = NULL.  This of course would be *bad*.